# What is the difference of adding increment after procedure i while loop

Tags: python, loops, oop, while-loop

**what is the difference of these two code where i get infinity loop on first snippet**

```
while (e <5):
   print("hello)
    e = e+1
```

**regular while loop in the second snippet**

```
 while (e <5):
   e = e+1
   print("hello)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both code snippets work as expected.
You might have indentation issue in the first code snippet.

```
e = 0
while e < 5:
   print("hello")
   e = e + 1

e = 0
while e < 5:
   e = e + 1
   print("hello")
```

Comment: He missed a `"` in `print("hello)`, which you did not.